# How to save user's rating and comment when they press Submit button?

Tags: java, android, button, save, comments

I'm a beginner programmer and I'm working on an app which displays some items. The user can click on any item , read it's description and also rate and comment on it. I created a rating bar and a comments section (and also a textview which shows the average rating).

I want the rating and the comment of each user to be saved when they press the button mSendFeedback. How can I do that?

Java file of an item's page

```
public class ItemDemo extends AppCompatActivity {
    RatingBar mRatingBar;
    TextView mRatingScale;
    TextView averageRating;
    EditText mFeedback;
    Button mSendFeedback;
    int i=0;
    float total = 0;
    float average;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_event_demo);

        mRatingBar = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);
        mRatingScale = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvRatingScale);
        mFeedback = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etFeedback);
        mSendFeedback = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);


        mRatingBar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float v, boolean b) {
                mRatingScale.setText(String.valueOf(v));
                switch ((int) ratingBar.getRating()) {
                    case 1:
                        mRatingScale.setText("Bad");
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        mRatingScale.setText("Okay");
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        mRatingScale.setText("Not bad");
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        mRatingScale.setText("Good enough");
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        mRatingScale.setText("Perfect");
                        break;
                    default:
                        mRatingScale.setText("");
                }
            }
        });

        mSendFeedback.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (mRatingBar.getRating() == 0.0) {
                    Toast.makeText(EventDemo.this, "Please enter a rating", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    mFeedback.setText("");
                    mRatingBar.setRating(0);
                    i=i+1;
                    total += mRatingBar.getRating();
                    average = total /i ;
                    Toast.makeText(EventDemo.this, "Thanks for the rating", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.averageRating);
        textView.setText("average rating: " +average+"/5 stars");
    }



}
```

XML file of an item's page

```
 <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="177dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/item1" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView11"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/imageView4"
                android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
                android:gravity="center|center_horizontal"
                android:text="Item 1"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
                android:textColor="@color/design_default_color_primary_dark"
                android:textColorHighlight="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:textColorLink="@color/design_default_color_primary"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                tools:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView12"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/textView11"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="This is the description of item 1"
                android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                android:textStyle="italic"
                tools:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

            <RatingBar
                android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/textView12"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:numStars="5"
                android:stepSize="1" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvRatingScale"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/ratingBar"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/averageRating"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/tvRatingScale"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etFeedback"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/averageRating"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:hint="add a comment"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:lines="5" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnSubmit"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="#e57373"
                android:text="Submit Feedback"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice if you could mention where you want to save it? Locally or on some server/cloud? I'm assuming the second option as the purpose of a rating given by a user is that it should be visible to other users as well.

If this is the case, I'd suggest using [Firebase Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/) for it.

What you should do is create a class for it like say:

```
class Rating {
    int value;
    Date date;
}
```

You have to store the rating given in an object of the above class. You can then store these objects in the Firebase Realtime Database.

If you have a user registration process, store the user id too to avoid duplicate ratings.

Using Firebase is extremely easy and convenient for such purposes. Following their sample with the Android Studio plugin, you'll be done doing this in minutes time.